# python3: can't open file - How to access directories with Docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I have tried multiple options but I just can't figure out how to
access my starting foo.py file which is hiden in my directory structure.

The structure looks like this:

```
D:
│___ Dockerfile
│
└───Level1
    └───Level2
            foo.py
```

Now to start the project I need to access the foo.py file, which then works with different files spread
over Level1 and 2.
The problem is that I am not able to access the foo.py file with something like:

```
COPY /Level1 .    
CMD ["python3", "/Level1/Level2/foo.py"]
```

The error `is python3: can't open file`

Please help

Comment: "python3: can't open file" Is that the full error?

Comment: you need to copy the file to your contaoner using Dokcerfile or using volumes

Comment: What have you already done to try to debug the issue?  For instance, have you looked at the filesystem layout using a debugging shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is wrong. Change your CMD from `CMD ["python3", "/Level1/Level2/foo.py"]` to `CMD ["python3", "/Level2/foo.py"]`

You are copying from `Level1/` to `.`, so you lose that Level1 folder.

As a side note, please include the entire error message in the post. the error message `can't open file` is very confusing, however the error message `python3: can't open file '/Level1/Level2/foo.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` is very clear.